# Python - qpython scrip to get a CPU ID or Hardware ID

Tags: python, android, qpython

I am beginner in Python coding, I try to create a little python script to get/read a `CPU ID` or `Hardware ID`, `Android ID` or if there are others Unique ID to get/read easy from android devices even better that is compatible with Q-Python, I need just a little help for a few lines code for one of those Unique ID that with work in an android emulator or android phones to get any Unique ID, for example I try with module `subprocess.check_output()` and I couldn't make it to work for my.

So any help will make my happy to get it work and run in **QPython**, with module `subprocess.check_output()` or with others modules that will work fine!

Thanks Stack Overflow and to all Python DevPro

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site where you can ask questions about **programming**. Finding code for you is not programming.

Comment: I know, but I have no idea how to create the code to read example CPU ID!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Okay i have edited my question and make it more cleared. Thanks Stack Overflow.